# PHP if statement inside HTML

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I am checking if the value stored in my variable is equal to 0 or 1. 
Depending on the value, I want to display some text inside my html form. 
The value that I have inside $details['status'] is 0 of type string. 
When I print_r() outside of the if-else structure, the result is 0. 
However, if I print_r() inside the if statements, I get nothing back. 
I did a var_dump() and the the values is of type string

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/MVC/teacher/becomeTeacher" method="post">
    <?php print_r($details['status'])?> <!-- Gives me 0 -->

    <?php if($details['status'] === 1): ?>
        This will show if the status value is 1.
    <? elseif ($details['status'] === 0): ?>
        Otherwise this will show.
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

I tried multiple options.

Option A - Both if statements execute.

```
<?php if($details['status'] == 0): ?>
        This will show if the expression is true.
    <? elseif ($details['status'] == 1): ?>
        Otherwise this will show.
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Option B - Both if statements execute

```
<?php if($details['status'] === '0'): ?>
        This will show if the expression is true.
    <? elseif ($details['status'] === '1'): ?>
        Otherwise this will show.
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I found a solution but I find it redundant

```
<?php if($details['status'] === '1'): ?>
        This will show if the expression is true.

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($details['status'] === '0'): ?>
        Otherwise this will show.
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is the `$details['status']` type? String or Int?

Comment: Have you tried a simple `==` comparison?

Comment: Did you determine it was an int with `var_dump` or with the result of `print_r`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

You are missing the php from `<?` on the elseif line. It should be `<?php` unless you have short tags enabled, which I'm guessing you don't.

```
<?php if($details['status'] == 0): ?>
        This will show if the expression is true.
    <? elseif ($details['status'] == 1): ?>
        Otherwise this will show.
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php if($details['status'] == 0): ?>
        This will show if the expression is true.
    <?php elseif ($details['status'] == 1): ?>
        Otherwise this will show.
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the "===" , === is used to compare for exact type, i think in your case, $detail['status'] = "0" is actually string, so it will not get into any of your if statement.

[Here a reference to php comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Hope it helps.

In your case, either change the if statement to `$details['status'] == 0 or $details['status'] === '0'` will solve your problem.